# How can I watch the main London new year fireworks display after ordinary tickets have sold out?

Tags: london, public-holidays

I finally got my visa yesterday and went to check for the fireworks tickets, but [they're sold out](https://www.london.gov.uk/events/2016-12-31/london-new-years-eve-fireworks-2016?source=vanityurl).

- Is there any way I can still buy a ticket online? They are usually sold for £10, I'm interested in any alternative ways to see the fireworks, including any ways to buy sell-on tickets (I'm willing to pay around £30).
- If not, where else can I watch the fireworks, knowing that I'd be alone that night.

Comment: If they are sold out already, then likely you will pay a premium to a scalper to get one, not find them at bargain prices.

Comment: Yes OK I'm up for that, how/where?

Comment: Hopefully someone from London will chime in on that aspect.

Comment: Do you want the boat tickets or the bleachers tickets?  Also North or South side?  And would you give an indicative price you are willing to pay.

Comment: No not the boat tickets, the regular ones that are usually sold for £10. I'm willing to pay around £30.

Comment: My suggestions are a bit more pricey than that, but certainly nothing prevents your finding a spot on Bankside to watch the show for free.

Comment: @Gayot she doesn't know London so why not write that up as an answer - where on bankside/elsewhere can she watch for free?

Comment: The question is perfectly fine as the fireworks are a huge event that's of interest to many visitors.

Comment: @user568458 I see there's an answer, but I can add one also without any overlap or repetition.

Comment: I have cast a vote, because this question seems, to me, as exact representative "price shopping" closure. I specifically have waited for answers to be given, because I see the usefulness and value of it, yet do not wish this to be used, in the future, for a "but this question did it" rebuttal to a closure.

Answer (score 13):

My normal suggestion for [the New Year's Eve fireworks](https://www.london.gov.uk/events/2016-12-31/london-new-years-eve-fireworks-2016) is to book a river facing room at the [Tower Hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_Hotel,_London) and watch the show from a higher vantage point with an unobstructed view. It's preferred because it's (a) inside; and (b) relaxed; and (c) has a mini-bar; and (d) safe.

Secondarily, the same hotel has a roof-top bar and a restaurant/bar on the second floor. See the image below...

[image]

For other ideas, if you don't mind standing outside, here's the general rule of thumb...

> From any place in Greater London, if you can see the [London Eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Eye), you
>   will be able to see the fireworks.

So this would include venues as far downstream as [The Royal Observatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Observatory,_Greenwich) and as far north as [Alexandra Palace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandra_Palace).

[Primrose Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primrose_Hill) is a great example of a *safe* venue that provides an excellent view along with elegant surroundings. Here's a screen shot from Google Street View...

[image]

Arguably the best free spot is directly on [Tower Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_Bridge) (shown in the restaurant/bar photo above). On either side of river there are places to stand where you can avoid the GBP 10 ticket price. The downside is that I would be reluctant to confirm that the Tower Bridge area on New Year's eve is particularly safe (especially compared to Cannon Street or Greenwich or Primrose Hill), but that's an *opinion*.

---

Tip: take an iPad or other tablet with you and tune in to the BBC's coverage as they pass the book from Moscow to Prague to Paris and finally London.  That way you can pick up their commentary and see the fireworks both personally and on camera.

Comment: Not 100% sure about the Tower Bridge area idea. On the bridge itself might be a good view (very crowded though) but I was down outside the hotel you mention for New Year a few years ago and the view wasn't great (seemed safe-ish, crowds of 99% tourists, many filming on ipads), could only see the very high fireworks over the southbank buildings. A very high room might have a better view. Your "can you see the London Eye" rule of thumb and other suggestions are very good but you *can't* see the London Eye from Tower Bridge / Tower of London, it's around the bend

Answer (score 6):

Here is a 2012 map of the area for the fireworks display. Not much has changed in 4 years so this should still apply. The orange areas is for ticket holders.

My best bet would be the area north of Lambeth Bridge around embankment/houses of parliament. There is a small park here and there are good views up the river from this area.

[image]

Failing that the London NYE fireworks event is also broadcast live on BBC One. All TV's in the UK with signal have access to BBC One. As the most viewed channel most people have this on their TV during the New Years Eve night.

The BBC are also doing a [360 online view](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/1dFb5FhHRGlDhZPyXZGKDmt/new-years-eve-on-bbc-one) of the event this year. BBC One is also accessible online via the iPlayer if in the UK.

Answer (score 5):

You can try looking for a second hand ticket on stubhub.co.uk.